# Azure AD as central auth server and Shibbolth as Service provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, idp, shibboleth-sp

We have SSO setup where  we are using PingFederate as Central auth server ( for authentication and authorization ) and Shibboleth as Service Provider for our application.
Is it possible to configure Azure Active Direcroty as Central auth server with Shibboleth as Service provider.
I have gone to many articles but did not find any relevant. 
We are now planning to replace PingFed with AzureAD as CAS .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Active Directory as an identity provider (for Authentication and authorization) and central auth server.

You can configure your Shibboleth application in Azure Active Directory and permit users to access the application.

User identity should be created and maintained in Azure Active Directory to perform the SSO.

Please check [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/blackboard-learn-shibboleth-tutorial) to configure the application in Azure Active Directory.